# Python: Variable keeping value after restart

Tags: python, function, variables

I am creating a basic Caesar Cypher in python and I have finished the main part of it (the cypher part) but as I have been testing the code I have found that my `shift` variable is keeping the same value when I use a function to restart the code, I have tried resetting all the variables but it has not changed the outcome, here is the code:

```
import sys
accept_yes = ["Yes", "yes", "Y", "y"]
accept_no = ["No", "no", "N", "n"]
accept_encrypt = ["Encrypt", "encrypt", "E", "e"]
accept_decrypt = ["Decrypt", "decrypt", "D", "d"]
accept_exit = ["Exit", "exit"]
norm_alph = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"]
crypt_alph = [""]

def Intro():
    encrypt_or_decrypt = input("Do you want to encrypt, decrypt or exit?: ") 
    if encrypt_or_decrypt in accept_encrypt:
        print("You chose encrypt")
        print("Enter a message to encrypt:  ") #Asks user for msg to encrypt
        Encrypt()
    elif encrypt_or_decrypt in accept_decrypt:
        print("You chose decrypt")
        print("Enter a message to decrypt:  ") #Asks user for msg to decrypt
        Decrypt()
    elif encrypt_or_decrypt in accept_exit:
        print ("Exiting...")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
        print("Please try again")
        Intro()

def Encrypt():
    en_or_de = ("")
    msg = input("").lower()
    crypt_msg = ("")
    shift = int(input("Enter a number to offset by\n"))
    shift = shift + 1
    for en_or_de in range(0,26):
        crypt_alph.append(norm_alph[(en_or_de+shift)%26])
    for en_or_de in msg:
        if norm_alph.count(en_or_de):
            crypt_msg += crypt_alph[norm_alph.index(en_or_de.lower())]
        else:
          crypt_msg += en_or_de
    print (crypt_msg.upper())
    Intro()

def Decrypt():
    en_or_de = ("")
    msg = input("").lower()
    crypt_msg = ("")
    shift = ("")
    shift = int(input("Enter a number to offset by\n"))
    shift = shift - 1
    for en_or_de in range(0,26):
        crypt_alph.append(norm_alph[(en_or_de-shift)%26])
    for en_or_de in msg:
      if norm_alph.count(en_or_de):
        crypt_msg += crypt_alph[norm_alph.index(en_or_de.lower())]
      else:
        crypt_msg += en_or_de
    print (crypt_msg.upper())
    Intro()

Intro()
```

I really hope someone can help me because I have been stuck with this problem for a while.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: BTW, it's really a good idea to keep function names in lowercase, as per PEP8: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names  Right now they look like classes.

Comment: "restarting" a function by calling it again inside a function that the first function called is generally a bad idea, because the original function is still executing; the new one doesn't replace the old one or anything. And if you go too deep, you'll get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`. It's better to use a loop for this sort of control flow.

Comment: You `encrypt` and `decrypt` functions are 99% identical. Try to merge them into one function using another parameter that can be either `+1` or `-1`.

Comment: It is not "restarting". It is "recursively calling". So the value of `shift` will reset at each call, but after return it will have the previous value, corresponding to that call.

Comment: What Kevin said. So get rid of those calls to `Intro()` inside of Encrypt(), `Decrypt`, & `Intro()` itself, and re-write `Intro()` to use a `while True:` loop. And as tobias_k said, you could simplify your code so that it uses one function that can handle both encryption & decryption. There are various other things that can be done to improve your program, but don't worry about that at this stage. (But it's probably a good idea to fix your function names, as per frnhr's suggestion).

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the `crypt_alph` list is getting set by the first time you call your function, and then each subsequent time the `Encrypt()` function is called, the new `crypt_alph` contents are getting appended to the `crypt_alph` from the first call.

I've added a line to print `crypt_alph` so you can see what's happening:

```
Do you want to encrypt, decrypt or exit?: e
You chose encrypt
Enter a message to encrypt:  
Hello World
Enter a number to offset by
3
crypt_alph: ['', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c']
JGNNQ YQTNF
Do you want to encrypt, decrypt or exit?: e
You chose encrypt
Enter a message to encrypt:  
Hello World
Enter a number to offset by
4
crypt_alph: ['', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
JGNNQ YQTNF
Do you want to encrypt, decrypt or exit?: exit
Exiting...
```

See how the second time `crypt_alph` is printed it is way long?

The short explanation of why this happens is that global lists in python can be changed with actions like `append()`. To fix your issue, you should move `crypt_alph` into your function, like this:

```
def Encrypt():
    crypt_alph = [""]
    en_or_de = ("")
    msg = input("").lower()
    crypt_msg = ("")
    shift = int(input("Enter a number to offset by\n"))
    shift = shift + 1
    for en_or_de in range(0,26):
        crypt_alph.append(norm_alph[(en_or_de+shift)%26])
    for en_or_de in msg:
        if norm_alph.count(en_or_de):
            crypt_msg += crypt_alph[norm_alph.index(en_or_de.lower())]
        else:
          crypt_msg += en_or_de
    print (crypt_msg.upper())
    Intro()
```

It's a tricky little feature of globals in python. In general, it is a good idea to avoid globals!

Comment: Thanks! this really helped!!